# Excel: how to get column index number for the last column when the last column changes number

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to automate my VLOOKUPs for a data sheet that gets updated every week. At the moment my VLOOKUP looks like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,'[Report.xlsm]All'!$I:$OA,COLUMN('[Report.xlsm]All'!$NX:$NX)-8,0)
```

Every week two new columns are inserted to the table (before the last column). The new columns are populated with new data and I have to re-write my VLOOKUP.

The columns I'm looking up are always the third last, second last, and last columns.

Is there a way I can assign column index number with a function that looks up third last, second last, and last columns? I think that way I can add a macro that does the job for me.

Comment: I'm confused by your title. In your title it appears that the root of the problem is `COLUMN()-3 function` but you don't mention that anywhere else in your question or code.  What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: I rewrote the title now, do you think it's a little more clear? I haven't tried anything yet apart from looking into INDEX and MATCH functions but they don't provide the solution. I'm looking into someone else's VBA code who have done something similar but it's too confusing since I've only started using macros three days ago :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by using the MIN and COLUMN(S) functions:

For the last column: `MIN(COLUMN(range)+COLUMNS(range)-1)`

For the second last column: `MIN(COLUMN(range)+COLUMNS(range)-2)`

This is the code in full:

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim DataWorkbook As String
Dim DataWorksheet As String
Dim Data As String
On Error Resume Next

'Input box asking for a range of cells for subsequent VLOOKUPs'
Set Rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select data range:", Type:=8)
If Rng Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Macro Stopped"
Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

DataWorkbook = Rng.Worksheet.Parent.Name
DataWorksheet = Rng.Worksheet.Name

Data = "'[" & DataWorkbook & "]" & DataWorksheet & "'!" & Rng.Address

    'VLOOKUPS'
    'Column Index for VLOOKUP is MIN(COLUMN(range)+COLUMNS(range)-4) where -4 is the number of columns before the desired column'
    ActiveWorkbook.Activate

    'Third last column'
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A3, " & "'[" & DataWorkbook & "]" & DataWorksheet & "'!" & Rng.Address & ", MIN(COLUMN(" & "'[" & DataWorkbook & "]" & DataWorksheet & "'!" & Rng.Address & ")+COLUMNS(" & "'[" & DataWorkbook & "]" & DataWorksheet & "'!" & Rng.Address & ")-4),0)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D3:D116")
```

Answer (score 1):

For the last column, you may use below code and decrement it by 3

```
Dim lastcolumn As Long
dim ws as worksheet

set ws = activesheet

lastcolumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

for formula solution, you may use counta function in order to find the last column if your dataset has no blank headers.

if you find any problem, we can modify the code later

Comment: Thanks. How would I write it up in a VLOOKUP though?

Comment: I couldnt guess how to use. Is it possible to provide a sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Turn your data into an Excel table and then use the `.Range.columns.count`. You can turn into a table using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd> with a cell in the range selected. Ensure prompt includes all required columns. This is a robust method.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim totalColumns As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All").ListObjects(1)     
        totalColumns = .Range.Columns.Count
        Debug.Print totalColumns                 '<==All columns
        If totalColumns < 4 Then Exit Sub
        Debug.Print totalColumns - 3             '<== etc
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Using Ctrl + T wiped my whole data table - headings are just Column1,2,3,etc. and there's no data and the formatting is gone. Then it crashed Excel altogether :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Ctrl + T, unless you have set it to something else, is an inbuilt short cut for building a table. It doesn't wipe table. It only creates them and prompts you before doing so. It will change the existing formatting though (sorry).

Comment: That's ok, I have copies of sheets that I'm experimenting on, they're not original documents. By the way, what was the purpose of creating a new table? I would be essentially creating a copy of a table that already exists. Or is there something I'm not getting?

Comment: It is and isn't a new table. It converts/replaces your existing table with a table that Excel recognises as  a listobject and therefor exposes the properties and methods of ListObject such as .Range.Columns.Count

Comment: Ok, but how do I write it up as Vlookup formula?

Comment: =VLOOKUP(whatever,range, totalColumns,False)  ; =VLOOKUP(whatever,range, totalColumns-1,False) etc

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try this tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

With text column header labels in row 1 use,

```
=VLOOKUP(A3, '[Report.xlsm]All'!$I:$zz, match("zzz", '[Report.xlsm]All'!$1:$1)-8, false)
```

For dates or numbers in row 1, use 1e99 instead of "zzz".

Comment: What's the significance of me running VLOOKUP on column header labels?

Comment: I tried this method, typing in `=VLOOKUP(A3,'[Report.xlsm]All'!$A:$zz,MATCH("1e99", '[Report.xlsm]All'!$2:$2),0)` but it's not showing the results from the columns I need. I'm not actually sure what data it's looking up, it's miss matched :(